# MySQL Constraint - exactly one column out of a set must be non null?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I Have a MySql (InnoDb) table representing comments made about one of many types of objects.  Because I'm using [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html), I have a different foreign key for each type of object (store, category, item) shown below.  For each record, exactly one foreign key must be set and the other two must be null.  How can I specify this constraint in MySql?

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_comment` (
  `comment_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  /* primary key */
  `_user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,   /* foreign key to user table - always set (NOT NULL) */

  `store_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  /* foreign key to store table */
  `category_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  /* foreign key to category table */
  `item_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,  /* foreign key to item table */
...
```

Comment: With a trigger, for one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_insert AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_comment`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.category = NULL, NEW.item = NULL;
END;
```

Comment: Is this just setting values to NULL?  How is it different from declaring a foreign key to be DEFAULT NULL?